# Linq to sql - saving multi level nested children with a new entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have an entity, which contains a child that has many levels, like this:

```
parent -> List<ChildEntity> ChildEntities
            ChildEntity -> List<ChildEntity> ChildOfChildEntities
```

If I'm saving a new parent, how can I link the child to the parent, AND the children of the child to the parent?

If I would have only one level, I would add to the collection of the parent, but now, if I do that, only the first level will be associated to the parent.

edit: the parent is not the same type as the child, and all the multi level of the children need to have an FK to the top level parent. If I do like you say, the relation between the child will be OK, but the second level and more of the child won't have the FK to the top level parent.

Comment: In your structure - `ChildOfChildEntities` don't need to be linked to the `parent` - but only to their respective parent from the `ChildEntities` collection.

Comment: I was not clear I think, the parent is not the same type as the child, and all the multi level of the children need to have an FK to the top level parent. If I do like you say, the realtion between the child will be OK, but the second level and more of the child won't have the FK to the top level parent.

Comment: It depends on the model.  If the model has Primary Keys linking tables then the children with the same keys are automatically associated to the parent.

Comment: There are primary keys, but the second level and more of the child don't end up with the FK to the parent UNLESS I flatten all my objects and set them to first child of the parent.

Comment: Are you using EF / EF Core? (just to be clear, one of your tags suggests otherwise)

Comment: Good point, I'm on EF 6.3 now, not core.

Comment: FYI: The description for the [tag:linq-to-sql] tag reads: *"LINQ to SQL is a component of .NET Framework version 3.5 that provides a run-time infrastructure for managing relational data as objects stored in Microsoft SQL Server"* That's not Entity Framework. It's the thing that came before it. [tag:linq-to-entities] states *"...LINQ queries using the ADO.NET Entity Framework. Note that this is different than LINQ to SQL..."*

Comment: Why do the "grandchildren" need a direct reference to the root of this structure ("`parent`")? When there are identifying foreign keys, you'll have something that looks like that but the grandchild only *refers* to its parent (child of root) even though you can join directly to the grandparent.